# Call PendingIntent from helper class

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I've made a NotificationHelper in my Android app, that is surpose to handle my notifications throughout the app.

And if i move my two methods (showNotification + stopNotification) to let's say a fragment, then its working perfectly fine :-)

But the moment, I try to access the same two methods (the methods are identical) from my NotificationHandler, then i get this exception :'(

And I have been trying to figure out now for nearly 3 hours why that is ??!

[exception from log.cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYpta.png)

It looks like the error is regarding : getApplicationContext() in this line :

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION);

=== Here's my NotificationHandler ===

```
public class NoteHandler extends Application {



/**
 *  Empty constructor
 */
public NoteHandler() {

}

/**
 *  Turning Notification ON
 */
public void showNotification() {



    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    // Setting LIGHTS and RINGTONE
                    .setLights(Color.WHITE, 300, 100)
                    //.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    // Setting the ICONS
                    //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_switch_flash_on))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    // Setting the CONTENT
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.app_notification_flash))
                    // Setting the INTENT
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true);

    // Setting the color of SmallIconBackground (only for Android API 21 and above...)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#6b394c"));
    }

    // Setting Priority to MAX (only for Android API 16 and above...)
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    }

    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 1;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

/**
 *  Turning Notification OFF
 */
public void stopNotification() {
    int mNotificationId = 1;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.cancel(mNotificationId);
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you call showNotification from? 
Helper class are usually done with static method, and you need to pass context into it, not by extending Application.

Comment: Since this helper is surposed to taking care of a notification, then i'cant use static methods... Im calling from both MainActivity and Fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper class containing only static methods. Remove this from your `Application` class. Since the static methods need access to a `Context`, just pass that in as a parameter when you call it. Example:

```
public static void showNotification(Context context) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION);
    ...
}
```

Use the `context` variable every time you need a `Context`. Your `Activity` should call the method with `this` as the `Context`, and your `Fragment` can use `getActivity()` as the `Context`.

Comment: WOW Thank you David !! I see now, that I forgot to pass in the context into the method... Dough!

Comment: I have a thought dough ?! Is there any partically reason, why helperclass' should always be static ??

Comment: 'static' isn't a **must**, but usually you collect methods in to helper classes that can be called from anywhere, therefore the class doesn't need to have any state (ie: member variables), therefore the methods can be`static`. It is just a best-practice.